# android reduce space between two vertical TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two vertical TextView elements in my app.
There is lot of space between TextViews, pading and layoutMargin are 0

Is there way to reduce this space?

[image: On image space between two text views-padding and margin are 0]

EDIT
Here is my code:

```
.
.

<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/home_tab_text_normal"
                    android:text="Test1"/>
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Text2"/>


        </LinearLayout>         

.
.
```

Thnaks

Comment: Show your code, it might be because of the TextViews parent layout' settings

Comment: @Zsolt Safrany this question is older, duplicate can be only newest question :)

Comment: @Jovan Doesn't really matter. They ask the same question and that one has a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negative Margins can be set by two methods -

1) by xml - set the "android:Layout_marginTop" field negative - which other people have already suggested above

2) by java (Programmatically) - set the "topMargin" field of LayoutParams to negative.

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769815/remove-space-between-stacked-textviews/16932953#16932953)

Comment: this is an unsupported solution.  works now, but still unsupported.

Answer (score 18):

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try by giving negative margin to any of the layout.
Like for the second tv you can give:-

android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"

or

for the first tv:-

android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"

You might need to change the values as per your requirement