# Remove space between stacked TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with two `TextView` inside it. The former contains a static text property (it's text never change) and the last contains a regressive timer. The image below shows both items:

[image: stacked textviews]

I want to eliminate the blank space that both texts have both top and bottom. I've tried several approaches...

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
```

...but none of them removed the space above the text. How can I make both texts close to each other without any extra space?

PS: I've found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162500/android-reduce-space-between-two-vertical-textviews), but no one answered it.

---

Full layout code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/boxTime"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRemainingTime2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_heigh="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRemainingTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_heigh="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:textSize="107sp"
        android:text="@string/timer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using negative margins.  It may take a bit of playing with the numbers to get it right, but I've done it before and it worked out well.

```
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
```

Comment: Actually I had used this for a long time and never got a problem, but I keep in doubt if is this really a good solution, but I can't see a better one.

Comment: @PozzoApps It's a workaround more than a fix, but it does do the job nicely, so...

Answer (score 30):

By default, a [TextView includes some padding to leave space for accent characters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setIncludeFontPadding%28boolean%29). You can turn that off with:

```
 android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

or

```
 textView.setIncludeFontPadding(false)
```

Comment: it works for me. but still some space is there in ascender and descender of text how to remove this?

Answer (score 17):

Make baseline of the text equal to the bottom of the TextView.

```
public class BaselineTextView extends TextView {

    public BaselineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int yOffset = getHeight() - getBaseline();
        canvas.translate(0, yOffset);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

NOTE: To avoid chopping off descenders call `setClipChildren(false)` on your `TextView`'s parent `ViewGroup` (`android:clipChildren="false"` in XML).

Comment: This works perfectly for any font, font size, screen density, etc. Why isn't it the accepted answer ?

Comment: This is really the most convenient answer of all.

Comment: All this does it move the padding to the top of the view, so it's still there and has to be accounted for in any design work.

Comment: Copied the code above into my project. It has the effect of chopping off descenders.

Comment: @macu, you may have to call setClipChildren(false) on your TextView's parent ViewGroup.

Comment: Better solution is to set the height using the baseline. As in:

Comment: The only answer that has worked for me. Thanks.
Note: Because, I was using FontFitTextView. :)

Comment: This is the only answer that works. Thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

If you set **includeFontPadding** to false it helps.

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

but if you know you don't have any descenders because you set

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

or you know there are no characters which have descender, you can make a custom TextView and set the height to the baseline.

```
public class ExTextView extends TextView {

    public ExTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ExTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ExTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        setHeight(getBaseline());  // <--- Shrink size to baseline
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The source code is included in my UiComponents test app.
https://github.com/landenlabs/UiComponents

Answer (score 2):

Just use below, nothing else required.

```
 android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

if you want some variations in line gap then use :

```
android:lineSpacingExtra
```

Answer (score 1):

negative margins will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Since my requirement is override the existing textView get from `findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("xxx", "id", "android"));`, so I can't simply try `onDraw()` of other answer.

But I just figure out the correct steps to fixed my problem, here is the final result from Layout Inspector:

[image]

Since what I wanted is merely remove the top spaces, so I don't have to choose other font to remove bottom spaces.

Here is the critical code to fixed it:

```
Typeface mfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/myCustomFont.otf");
myTextView.setTypeface(mfont);

myTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

myTextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

The first key is set custom font "fonts/myCustomFont.otf" which has the space on bottom but not on the top, you can easily figure out this by open otf file and click any font in android Studio:

[image]

As you can see, the cursor on the bottom has extra spacing but not on the top, so it fixed my problem.

The second key is **you can't simply skip any of the code**, otherwise it might not works. That's the reason you can found some people comment that an answer is working and some other people comment that it's not working.

Let's illustrated what will happen if I remove one of them.

Without `setTypeface(mfont);`:

[image]

Without `setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`:

[image]

Without `setIncludeFontPadding(false);`:

[image]

Without 3 of them (i.e. the original):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Negative Margins would do the work. You can set it by two methods -

1) by xml - set the `android:Layout_marginTop="-10dp"` field negative

2) by java (Programmatically) - set the `topMargin` field of LayoutParams to negative.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the height of TextView and maybe change android:gravity="bottom"

height is between textsize and size of textView with Wrapcontent.

```
public class MyTextViewBounder extends TextView {
public MyTextViewBounder(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTextViewBounder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTextViewBounder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //test kích thước thực tế với kích thước của Textview bao quanh text của nó như thế nào
    int width, height;
    Paint iPaint;
    Rect  iRect = new Rect();

    iPaint = new Paint();
    iPaint.setTextSize(13);
    iPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    //call below code outsite
    //this.setText("Hung");
    //this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,13);
    //this..setIncludeFontPadding(false);   //height from 18px down to 15px
    iPaint.getTextBounds("Hung",0,4,iRect); //width = 34px, height = 12px

    width = this.getWidth(); //= 30px
    height = this.getHeight(); //= 18px

    width = this.getMeasuredWidth(); //=30px
    height = this.getMeasuredHeight(); //= 18px

    width = iRect.width();  //34px
    height = iRect.height(); //12 px

}
```

}