# TextView spacing is inconsistent with new line characters

Tags: android, textview, spacing

I want the spacing between between "Hello World" to be equal to the spacing between "Stack Overflow", while maintaining the spacing between "World" and "Stack". "Hello World" is contained inside one `TextView`, with a line break "Hello \n World".  The "Stack Overflow" is split into two `TextView` elements. I know I can use `lineSpacingExtra` in the layout for `myTextView`, but this also adds unwanted spacing below  "World".

Is there an elegant way to achieve equal spacing? One idea is to split "Hello World" between two `TextView` elements, and use regular expressions to split when I see a new line character, but this is a bit of a hack.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_wraptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stack"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overflow"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.example.TextViewSpacingExample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewSpacing extends Activity {

    private TextView myTextView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_wraptext);
        myTextView.setText("Hello \nWorld");
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Stack and overflow are two different textviews..And you printing Hello World in Single TextView

Comment: Yes, I want the spacing to be the same regardless.

Comment: why would you split strings into different textviews? maybe you don't really need that...do some strings has to be loaded dynamically while others are set from xml?

Comment: In the context of my app it makes sense.  The first `TextView` could represent a name, which is being passed from my database as "First Name \n Last Name".  The other two `TextView`s could be independent bits of information like "marital status" and "favorite ice cream".

Comment: mmm...what about appending other informations to the first textview? I still don't understand the need of more than one textview, unless you want to change views style

Comment: I've abstracted away from my actual design for the sake of simplicity and to highlight my particular problem.  Having everything in one TextView is not an option for design reasons.  There must be a way to make the spacing equal in the problem I've laid out. At the very least, there is obviously some sort of default padding around a `TextViews`. Otherwise, the spacing between "Stack" and "Overflow" would be smaller.  Does anyone know how to find the default vertical padding for `TextViews`?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769815/remove-space-between-stacked-textviews? It might help.

Comment: sorry for playing devil's advocate...is using some `Spannable`s within a single textview not an option too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redesigning two "Stack" and "Overflow" `TextView`s to one `TextView` with a `SpannableString` because it was the least hacky solution.