# How to reduce line spacing between two textviews within the Relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

By default it takes 1 line spacing in between two textviews. How to reduce it?

Comment: how you set properties on textviews show it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative Margins can be set

```
android:Layout_marginTop="-10dp"
```

or you can use

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Refer : [Remove space between stacked TextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769815/remove-space-between-stacked-textviews)

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Thanks dude, made my day

Answer (score 2):

give negative value in `android:lineSpacingExtra`